# How to share image to facebook with onclick image to redirect specific link using javascript.?

Tags: javascript, php, image, facebook, codeigniter

I need to share dynamic image from my website to facebook using javascript.

- MVC used for my site: **PHP Codeigniter**
- **Sample image** i would like to share:
  https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/11/19/44/fruit-2305192_960_720.jpg
- **Sample link** need to redirect onclick shared image:
  http://www.lipsum.com/

I used the below code:

HTML Code:

```
<div id="shareBtn" class="btn btn-success clearfix">Share</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: 'MY_APP_ID', cookie: true, status: true, version:'v2.10'
  });
};

document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'share',
    display: 'popup',
    href:'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/11/19/44/fruit-2305192_960_720.jpg',
  }, 
  function(response)
  {
    console.log("response: ");
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

Shared image gets posted and that shown below:

[image]

When click on shared image in facebook, i need to redirect to a specific url(http://www.lipsum.com/).

But now the url redirect to the same image url:
(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/11/19/44/fruit-2305192_960_720.jpg)

Due to dynamic image i don't need to use meta tag og informations in my site.

How to achieve this.?

Comment: _“But now the url redirect to the same image url”_ - of course it does - that _is_ the URL you shared. The only way this could work, is if you had control over the `cdn.pixabay.com` server, so that you could redirect requests by human visitors somewhere else.

Comment: @CBroe.. I can't able to control those redirects in my server. Its a dynamic image. And there is no other options available with FB.ui..?

Comment: you need to put the image in the og:image tag of the shared url, that is the only way

Comment: @luschn .. then, can you give code how the FB.ui function..? And also can you tell the website https://buffer.com will help for my need..?

Comment: You can not do this via FB.ui. You would need to share the URL of an HTML document, that contains the appropriate meta tags.

Comment: what code do you need? there is example code in the official docs - after all you just need to use the href parameter with the correct url and then put correct og tags into the shared url.

Comment: buffer.com is completely irrelevant for that topic, that platform is for scheduled posts

Comment: @CBroe .. Ok.. Can you give the sample code to share the url of html document for my case..?

Comment: @luschn .. thanks.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters